# Using jquery to generate a Slug from Title (on lost focus)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to use jquery to create a request to a controller action posting Title and getting back Slug. This needs to happen when user enters a title into a Title textbox on the form and then uses tab or enter to move to the next field. I do not want to convert title to slug in Javascript - I have a controller action set up to do it and it will return the correct slug (the controller action converts it and it also check the resulting slug for uniqueness).

I just need to achieve the "onLostFocus" effect on Title textbox and populate the Slug textbox.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

With your help I've come up with this:

```
$('#Title').blur(  
    function(){
        $.get('<%=Url.Action("TitleToSlug", "Services", new { title = HOW TO GET VALUE OF TITLE TEXTBOX HERE}) %>', function (data) {
            $('#Slug').val(data);
        });
    }  
)
```

How do I get the value for the Title textbox in the above code and provide it to the Url.Action() helper method so that it will generate the URL like this: ~/Services/TitleToSlug/my test title

thanks

Comment: Just a side note: If you use a system like StackOverflow where the slug in the URL is prefixed by the actual ID of the row, you don't have to worry about slug uniqueness. The slug in the URL should exist merely for readable URLs and searchability.

Comment: I am working on a system with an ID and Slug for content and a system with just a slug for content where the slug has to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use the [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event handler?

```
$( '.yourSelector' ).blur( 
    function(){ 
        // do stuff 
    } 
)
```

Comment: please see the edited answer if you can provide additional help